# Can gcc optimize const strings (rodata) that are the same, but declared in different modules?

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I'm using GCC for embedded, STM32 (arm-none-eabi-gcc latest) and I'm not clear about compiler optimization related to const string arguments (using -O3)

Considering this example

```
const char test[] = "testing string";

void foo(const char* str) {

    Uart1Puts(str);
}

void bar(const char* str) {

    Uart1Puts(str);
}
```

Calling like this

```
    foo("testing string");
    bar("testing string");
```

will produce the same result (size, ram) as

```
    foo(test);
    bar(test);
```

However, if I have another function in another module

```
extern const char test;
    void func_in_other_module(const char* str) {
    
        Uart1Puts(str);
    }
```

Calls will produce different results

```
func_in_other_module("testing string"); // bigger this one with approx. size of this string
func_in_other_module(test);
```

Now my question is can I convince GCC to figure out that consts are identical and should be one?

Comment: Did you try LTO? I did not the time being, it's just an idea.

Comment: Well.. GCC is not a linker, so no, it cannot. Maybe the linker can be smart and do it when linking the compilation units together, but at that point the compiler's job is done.

Comment: from: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html :
-fmerge-constants

    Attempt to merge identical constants (string constants and floating-point constants) across compilation units.

    This option is the default for optimized compilation if the assembler and linker support it. Use -fno-merge-constants to inhibit this behavior.
    Enabled at levels -O1, -O2, -O3, -Os.